# How would I write my name in kanji?

Tags: kanji

My name’s Ryan. I’ve been studying Japanese for a while now, and just for fun I’d like to know what my name would be in Kanji. 来安? 雷杏? Asking a native.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a foreign (Western) name in kanji for fun is not something an ordinary native Japanese speakers would do. We just use katakana for this purpose. That said, 来安 and 雷杏 both seem reasonable to me as a "kanji name for fun", and neither is more correct than the other. Many other kanji can be read ライ or アン, so there are many other possibilities. [来安 is a real place name](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lai%27an_County) in China, and it does look somewhat traditional. 雷杏 looks relatively more "pop" to my eyes.